# I am getting null parameter error in Flutter, how can I solve it?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm learning Flutter and I'm making an app as a demo, but I couldn't solve this error. Even though I have given values ​​to the parameter, when I run it, I get an error that it cannot be null.

**student.dart code**

```
class Student {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String status;
  int grade;

  Student(String firstName, String lastName, int grade) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.status = "Geçti";
    this.grade = grade;
  }
}
```

**main.dart code**

```
List<Student> students = [Student("Engin", "Demiroğ", 75), Student("İsmail", "Güner", 65), Student("Aykut", "Elmas", 88), Student("Cengiz", "Han", 100)];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Demo1"),
      ),
      body: buildBody(context),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: students.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Text(students[index].firstName);
              }),
        ),
```

**The error I got**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you enable null safety, then you must initialize the values of non-nullable variables before you use them.* Source: [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value) for more info.

[Null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) is enabled by default. As stated there, you need to assign a default value for those variables.

Your class can be rewritten using dart syntax sugar for initializing variables ([documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors))

```dart
class Student {
  String firstName = "";
  String lastName = "";
  String status = "";
  int grade = 0;
    
  Student(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.grade);
}
```

Using that syntax for initializing variables we don't need to specify a default value for them, so removing the unnecesary default values:

```dart
class Student {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  int grade;
  String status = "";
    
  Student(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.grade);
}
```

It's also common to declare variables initialized in the constructor as `final` (can only be initialized once)

```dart
class Student {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final int grade;
  String status = "";
    
  Student(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.grade);
}
```

I recommend taking a look at the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour)

Answer (score 3):

Dart has recently introduced null-safety. It prevents you from making a lot of mistakes. For more info: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

The best way to solve your problem is to understand what variables can be nullable or non-nullable.

```
class Student {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName; ///nullable
  String status; /// non-nullable
  int? grade;

  Student({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.status = 'Geçti', this.grade});
}
```

In this case, only the variable **status** can't be null, and it's value is set to *"Geçti"* by the constructor. All the other variables can be null.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the type of your variables are not nullable but you didn't initialize them with a value. To fix this use the keyword [late](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#late-variables).

```
class Student {
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String status;
  late int grade;

  Student(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.grade) {
    this.status = "Geçti";
  }
}
```

Comment: With the code you wrote, my code worked without any problems. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the question mark with the type of each property to indicate that it is nullable:

```
class Student {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? status;
  int? grade;
```

Dart is null-safe, so since you’re declaring new properties of a class without the question mark, it will interpret that the value will never be null, but initially their values are all null, thus the error. I suggest to read more on the [null safety feature](https://dart.dev/null-safety//) since it’s a pretty important concept for Dart/ Flutter.

P/s: To use the nullable property (for example `String? firstName`, use it with `??` for those widgets that don’t take in nullable value. For example:

```
Text(student.firstName ?? ‘Empty name’)
```

Here, the `??` has meaning that, if `student.firstName` is null, use this `Empty name` string as value. Since `Text` requires a non-null value, we need to make sure that in case the `firstName` is null, we have a default value in place to avoid passing nullable value in.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter can be serious concerning null values and initialization. Even if practically you assign values, it does not 'believe' you, and throws a build error. See [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety) for example. But for as a quick fix you can mark the members of **Student** class as **late**, practically you promise to Flutter, that later you will assign values:

```
class Student {
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String status;
  late int grade;
...
```

You have many other options, but this one works as a starter, I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

From Dart 2.12 you need to specify if your parameters are nullable or vice versa. Please see below code

```
class Student {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String status;
  final int grade;

  Student({required this.firstName, required this.lastName, required this.status, required this.grade,});
}
```